# Exclude specific endpoint in Jersey Logging

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey 2's Built in `LoggingFeature`. how can I exclude specific endpoint to be logged?

Example, the endpoint I would like to exclude is for health check endpoint, I would like to exclude it because its flooding my logging.